# Create a "sample by sample" model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to create a Model in Keras that can learn "sample by sample"; this type of machine is called [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning), a model that receives and fit data by data. My question is: 
How can I do that in Keras? Is it possible to do this just by setting `batch_size=1` while fitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Keras batch size has nothing to do with how data is fed in. Batch size determines how many parallel samples are going to be fed into the network per gradient update. A more clear explanation of batch size depends on what the network is. For example in a stateful RNN, batch size of N means the input tensor contains N independent series. A single batch process moves forward on all N series by one sample. So, in each batch, N samples (1 of each N independent series) are processed and the gradient is updated.

Therefore, in your case, it seems that there's only one stream for samples, If the samples are of type time series data, so we definitely have `batch_size=1`, If before deploying the model you have a data set to train the model on, you can read them all in memory and `fit` the model, and after deployment as new observations is provided you can `train_on_batch` or `fit` the model again and again. There's no limit how many times you `fit` the model.

Comment: It is more like a time series data. So once I've used `batch_size=1` I should use `train_on_batch` to upgrade the gradient of my model, rigth? PD: I can only use my dataset data by data, i mean, i can't `fit`  by taking all (or partial) of my dataset.

Comment: @Omar There's no difference, both `train_on_batch` and `fit` can be used. `train_on_batch` moves forward by one step but `fit` processes all available data passed to it. Since at each step you only have one sample, there's no difference between this two.